# Multiple form submission

Tags: javascript

```
function saveConfig(val)
{
    if(val == 1){       
        document.f1.submit();       
        document.f4.submit();       
    }
    else if(val == 2){              
        document.f2.submit();       
    }
    else if(val == 3){      
        document.f3.submit();       
    }
    document.f0.submit();
}
```

Hi The above code works well in IE6, IE7, IE8, FF3.0.19, FF3.5.19 and FF3.6.20. However it doesnot work on Firefox versions > 4. Please help me in understanding what was wrong with the above code.

Comment: Hi Ryan. There is no error on the firebug console. If val is 1 it just skips f1 and f4 form submits and jumps to f0 form submit which returns 302 HTTP code.

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all; if a form submits, how is it returning back to this javascript, to submit the next form?

Answer (score 0):

Can try by using
var form1=document.getElementsByName('f1');
form1.submit();

Comment: This is a direct error dump? A strange thing to see. Actually I believe you should use AJAX not the submit of a form as it should break after the first submit. If val = 1 then form4 should not be submitted. I will test once I will be at home :)

Comment: Hi YNR, I see the error "Object doesn't support this method" with the above changes

Answer (score 0):

```
function f0Submit() {
  document.f0.submit();
}

function f4Submit() {
  var dataString = $('f4').serialize();

    new Ajax.Request('url', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: dataString,
      onSuccess: function(data) {
                   f0Submit();
                 }
   });
}

function saveConfig(val) {
  if(val == 1) {
    var dataString = $('f1').serialize();

    new Ajax.Request('url', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: dataString,
      onSuccess: function(data) {
                   f4Submit();
                 }
    });
  }
  else if(val == 2){              
    var dataString = $('f2').serialize();

    new Ajax.Request('url', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: dataString,
      onSuccess: function(data) {
                   f0Submit();
                 }
    });       
  }
  else if(val == 3){      
    var dataString = $('f3').serialize();

    new Ajax.Request('url', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: dataString,
      onSuccess: function(data) {
                   f0Submit();
                 }
    });       
  }     
}
```

Comment: whats going on above, where you able you work it out and now your posting you working answer?

Comment: Hi David the above code worked for me so I thought of sharing the solution.